# libsvm data format

Tags: machine-learning, svm, python, libsvm, c++

I'm using the libsvm (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) tool for support vector classification. However, I'm confused about the format of the input data.

From the README:

> The format of training and testing data file is:
>
> ```
> <label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ...
> .
> .
> .
> ```
>
> Each line contains an instance and is ended by a '\n' character.  For
>   classification, `<label>` is an integer indicating the class label
>   (multi-class is supported). For regression, `<label>` is the target
>   value which can be any real number. For one-class SVM, it's not used
>   so can be any number.  The pair `<index>:<value>` gives a feature
>   (attribute) value: `<index>` is an integer starting from 1 and `<value>`
>   is a real number. The only exception is the precomputed kernel, where
>   `<index>` starts from 0; see the section of precomputed kernels. Indices
>   must be in ASCENDING order. Labels in the testing file are only used
>   to calculate accuracy or errors. If they are unknown, just fill the
>   first column with any numbers.

I have the following questions:

1. What is the use of the `<index>`? What purpose does it serve?
2. Is there a correspondence between the same index values of different data instances?
3. What if I miss/skip an index in between ?

I ask because the datafile *heart_scale* which is included in the package for libsvm, on line 12, the index starts from 2. Is the `<value>` for index 1 taken as unknown/missing?
Note: the tools/checkdata.py tool provided with the package says that the *heart_scale* file is correct.

Answer (score 25):

This link should help:
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#/Q3:_Data_preparation

It's mentioned that the data is stored in a sparse array/matrix form. Essentially, it means only the non-zero data are stored, and any missing data is taken as holding value zero. For your questions:

a) Index merely serves as a way to distinguish between the features/parameters. In terms of a hyperspace, it's merely designating each component:
Eg: 3-D ( 3 features) indices 1,2,3 would correspond to the x,y,z coordinates.

b) The correspondence is merely mathematical, when constructing the hyper-plane, these serve as coordinates.

c) If you skip one in between, it should be assigned a default value of zero.

In short,
+1 1:0.7 2:1 3:1 translates to:

Assign to class +1, the point (0.7,1,1).

Answer (score 5):

Just small and fast guide:

LibSVM format means that your document needs to be pre-processed already. You need to know how many classification classes will be used (most likely 2) and feature space.

**Classification class** is something like true/false; 0,1,... Here you need to transform it into integers (e.g. 0,1).

**Feature space** is a space for your multidimensional data. Each feauture (vector) should have its own ID (index) and its value. E.g. 1:23.2 means that feature/dimension 1 has value 23.2

```
<label> <index1>:<value1> <index2>:<value2> ... <indexN>:<valueN>
...
```

Comment: In the case of regression, you can replace <label> by <dep_var> (the target value to model)